# grep command on linux ( especially grep --exclude)

Tags: linux, grep, command

I'm newbie on linux issues and  before asking here I googled it however I couldnt find a clue about grep --exclude.So I wonder what does the line below ?? Thanks in advance

```
grep --exclude=\*.svn\* -r REVISION 1.0.0.8/*1.0.0.8.config > 1.0.0.8-REVISION.txt
```

**SOLVED BY MYSELF**

search REVISION on "1.0.0.8/*1.0.0.8.config" file exluding .svn file and send output to 1.0.0.8-Revision.txt

Comment: Are you asking what the line below does? Not sure exactly what your question is.

Comment: @MalcolmJones yea you're right.sorry for the language.

Answer (score 1):

To grep through a directory while excluding various file types (in your example anything prefixed with .svn ) you probably want to do the following:

```
grep -r "SOMETHING" --exclude="*.svn*" /path/to/directory >  1.0.0.8-REVISION.txt 2>&1
```

This will grep through all files within a directory recursively, then post the matches to a file called 1.0.0.8-REVISION.txt which is located relative to where you are currently searching.

If you provide more information abut exactly what you're trying to grep/find I can update my answer with something that will work exactly for your case.

Comment: So in my situation,grep will look into REVISION "1.0.0.8/*1.0.0.8.config" but for what ?? Am I right ?? @Malcolm-Jones

Answer (score 0):

you can find `grep` on man pages [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).

what exclude does:

--exclude=PATTERN:

- Recurse in directories skip file matching PATTERN.

your command will search, recursively, in all directories, skipping file pattern "*.svn*" and searching for file pattern "1.0.0.8/*1.0.0.8.config > 1.0.0.8-REVISION.txt"

Comment: let me correct If I'm wrong. In my case grep will look all the directories on .svn directory but for what ??

Comment: @Eday i've edited the answer, but i haven't ran it to test it. so you should do some grep commands to get the hang of it. let me know if something i've written is wrong so i'll fix the answer

Comment: what does the REVISION mean just after the -r ?

Comment: @Eday recursive search in the folder named REVISION

Comment: I have no folder such name

Comment: @Eday then it's meaningless. try some examples of grep to get the hang of it

Comment: meaningless  ? It is what I need.